# Java GUI Windows Classic

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, netbeans

I noticed in Netbeans you can preview your GUI through various screens (Windows, Windows Classic, Nimbus, etc). I'm pretty sure the default is Metal in Netbeans, but I want to change it to Windows Classic. Is this possible?

Would also like to know if its possible to change the edges to straight instead of rounded.

Cheers

Comment: Are you referring to the Look and Feel your app will be using, or just the netbeans default?

Comment: Sorry, didn't make that clear. The GUI of my program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The visual style of your application is known as a "look and feel".  [Check out the Java tutorial on them](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

From the tutorial:

```
try {
        // Set System L&F
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    } 
    catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    catch (InstantiationException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
```